# CS50 - make helpers.c

Tags: c, cs50

Maybe someone can give me a hint:

I have been trying to fix this error for several hours but somehow couldn't find the real issue. Could it be, that there is an issue with one of the other files (filter.c or bmp.h)?

I reiceive the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [<builtin>: helpers] Error 1**
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <math.h>
#include "helpers.h"

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; width > j; j++)
        {
            //dividing by 3 in order to get average color / grey tone
            // using float
            // using round
            float total = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            int average = (round)(total / 3); // 3 because of 3 colors RGB / Red, Green, Blue
            average = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
}

// Convert image to sepia
// Maximalwert von 255 Beachten --> hier am besten if condition > 255 dann etc
// round beachten // siehe hint
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; width > j; j++)
        {
            float green_before = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            float red_before = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            float blue_before = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            int green_after = (round)(.349 * red_before + .686 * green_before + .168 * blue_before);
            int red_after = (round)(.393 * red_before + .769 * green_before + .189 * blue_before);
            int blue_after = (round)(.272 * red_before + .534 * green_before + .131 * blue_before);

            if (green_after > 255)
            {
                green_after = 255;
            }

            if (red_after > 255)
            {
                red_after = 255;
            }

            if (blue_after > 255)
            {
                blue_after = 255;
            }
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green_after;
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = red_after;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue_after;


        }
    }
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width / 2; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE temp = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width - j - 1];
            image[i][width - j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

// Blur image

void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
     RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

     for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; width > j; j++)
         {
             int Green_insg = 0;
             int Red_insg = 0;
             int Blue_insg = 0;
             float counter = 0;

             for (int a = -1; 2 > a; a++)
             {
                 for (int b = -1; 2 > b; b++)
                 {

                     if (0 > i + a || i + a > height - 1 || 0 > j + b || j + b > width -1)
                     {
                         continue;
                     }
                     Green_insg += image [i+a][j+b].rgbtGreen;
                     Red_insg += image [i+a][j+b].rgbtRed;
                     Blue_insg += image [i+a][j+b].rgbtBlue;

                     counter++;
                 }
             }
                 // Durchschnittswerte der Nachbarpixel bilden
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(Green_insg/counter);
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(Red_insg/counter);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(Blue_insg/counter);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; width > j; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you're compiling an executable, it has to have a function called `main` somewhere. This will be called when the program starts. Do you have one? Not in the code you shared.

Comment: If you're compiling a library, you have to tell the compiler that that's what you're doing. We would have to discuss compiler and/or linker flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compiled some `C` code without telling `gcc` what kind of output you want.  When you do this, `gcc` will use a default setting, believing you want a runnable executable.

All runnable executables must have a entry point.  That entry point has a signature (a very specific function, with very specific types).  The signature required for `main` in a running executable should be written like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ...
}
```

Note that the `...` is not part of the C language, and should not be typed; rather the code you want executed should be typed there instead of typing `...`

If you wanted to not build an executable, there are other options available.  I won't list all of them, but a common one is:

```
-c
```

This halts compilation before linking, and writes a '.o' file, meaning if you were compiling `hello.c` you would get the output `hello.o` (which can't be executed, but can be combined easily into another executable (by linking) or can be combined into an archive `collection.a` (useful for passing lots of compiled items to other exectuables, as in when testing) or a shared library `collection.so` which is useful for a library purposefully built to be shared with other programs, or loaded by your own program optionally.

Since we don't know what you wanted `gcc` to do, hopefully it is coverer above; but, if it is not covered above, please submit a new question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Edwin Buck is correct to my knowledge. In this specific case of the "filter" problem from CS50, you should compile using `make filter` which uses the provided `Makefile` command to compile all the dependent files together. When you tried to compile only the `helpers.c` file you were asking to compile only that file, which doesn't have a `main` function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31138761)